# What can I do to my code to skip the first line of my input text file?

Tags: java

Here is my code :

```
public static double columnSum(String filename, int column) {
    double sum = 0;

    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Inout file " + filename + " does not exist");
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I would like to try and skip the first line of my text file in order to avoid the `NumberFormatException` error i'm getting but I don't know what to do to my code to do that.

this is an example of the file to read

```
Date,Temperature High,Temperature Low,Rain 
Junk line useless, data, at, every, column, in, this, line
Sat 3/7/2015,62,26,0 
Sun 3/8/2015,51,46,0.23 
Sat 3/14/2015,68,56,0 
useless, data, at, every, column, in, this, line. 
Sun 3/15/2015,69,54,0 
Mon 3/30/2015,78,60,0 
Tue 3/31/2015,84,65,0 
Wed 4/1/2015,81,66,0.04 
Thu 4/2/2015,85,69,0 
Fri 4/3/2015,74,60,0 
More junk 
Sat 4/18/2015,82,58,0.21 
Sat 4/25/2015,87,54,0 
Sun 4/26/2015,85,58,0.12 
Even more useless data. 
Sat 7/4/2015,94,77,0 
Sun 7/5/2015,84,79,0 
Mon 7/6/2015,93,78,0
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java

Comment: Just add a scan.nextLine(); after you created your scanner. It will read an entire line from your file and advance the current reading position. If you dont use the returned String it will simply be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
// skip first line
if(scan.hasNextLine()){
    scan.nextLine();
}
// then read the rest
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]);
}
```

also, don't forget to close the `Scanner`. Then your code should look like this

```
public static double columnSum(String filename, int column) {
    double sum = 0;

    try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
        if(scan.hasNextLine()){
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Inout file " + filename + " does not exist");
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Well the error is gone but now i'm getting the same answer regardless of what column I type in. Something wrong with my code in general then.

Comment: @AdrianGuerra you can give an example of the file you are reading

Comment: Date,Temperature High,Temperature Low,Rain
Junk line
useless, data, at, every, column, in, this, line.
Sat 3/7/2015,62,26,0
Sun 3/8/2015,51,46,0.23


Sat 3/14/2015,68,56,0
useless, data, at, every, column, in, this, line.
Sun 3/15/2015,69,54,0
Mon 3/30/2015,78,60,0
Tue 3/31/2015,84,65,0
 
Wed 4/1/2015,81,66,0.04
Thu 4/2/2015,85,69,0
Fri 4/3/2015,74,60,0



More junk
Sat 4/18/2015,82,58,0.21
Sat 4/25/2015,87,54,0
Sun 4/26/2015,85,58,0.12
Even more useless data.
Sat 7/4/2015,94,77,0
Sun 7/5/2015,84,79,0
Mon 7/6/2015,93,78,0

Comment: @AdrianGuerra before you do this: `sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]);` add a `System.out.println(s.split(",")[1])` in order to check what is happening. Maybe in some lines you are reading words instead of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Another solution as stated [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562551/what-can-i-do-to-my-code-to-skip-the-first-line-of-my-input-text-file#comment93990871_53562551) would be to surround the cast in a `try` `catch` block. As a `NumberFormatException` can happen anywhere in the file also.

```
public static double columnSum(String filename, int column) {
    double sum = 0;
    Scanner scan = null;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            try {
                sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
                // Do something else to handle it, or do nothing.
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Inout file " + filename + " does not exist");
    } finally {
        scan.close(); // Close it regardless of the result
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile, as your `scan` variable's scope is only within try block and hence you can't access it in `finally` block. You need to take `Scanner scan` declaration out side of `try` block.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Good catch.